# Svg icons don't shows in Qt GUI after deploying on target system.

Tags: svg, icons, qt5

I am using svg icons for my ActiveX component created by inherit from QAxWidget class. Icons saved in resource file, component built as InProcServer using VisualStudio 2015 and Qt 5.6.1. On my develop computer all works fine, but after deployig it to other systems, svg icons do not show up. After install qt plugins located in "plugins" subdir of installation directory and contains imageformats\qsvg.dll and iconengines\qsvgicon.dll files. qt.conf file contains following text:

[Paths]
plugins = plugins

What i am doyng wrong?